# Application Whitelisting

Tags: security, root, administration

How does an Ubuntu administrator implement application whitelisting?

For example, if I create a LAMP server and I only want SSH, Apache, MySQL and PHP to be able to execute. How can I prevent any other application from running?

Comment: By "any other application" are you including binaries and scripts that users may run?

Comment: Don't install applications you don't want to run on the server.

Comment: @robobenklein The goal is to not have any other applications run.

Comment: @Matthew If you allow users to log in, they are immediately able to run processes. If a user downloads a Shell Script, then runs it, there would be no way to prevent that action without limiting the user's ability to act as a user. For example, a user with no privileges anywhere or to anything could still create a /tmp directory or paste in shell code and run a basic program from there.